# RegEx to find multiple tags in specifed order

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,
I am using the latest release of NotePad++ and please I need help with a RegEx that will search multiple tagged words in the order I specify. Below is an example I have prepared:

`<first> <second> <third>` - Represent the three tags in the order I need the RegEx to find them in.

`<second> <first> <third>` - These tags are not in the order I need and therefore I want the RegEx to ignore them in the search.

`<third> <second> <first> <second> <second>`  - These tags are not in the order I need and also include duplicate tags I don't need the RegEx to include in the search.

I have already tried this RegEx: `(first | second | third)`

However, it seems to give me additional data I do not want. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not simply `(first second third)`? Ensures the order, ensures all three exist...

Comment: That's not valid XML. Do you mean `<first /> <second /> <third />` or `<first><second><third>match here</third></second></first>`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<first>[^<>]*<second>[^<>]*<third>
```

Comment: It seems to be more effective compared to what I using.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You've a bit of a difficult problem here, because ... pretty fundamentally, XML is hard to parse with regular expressions. There's a whole bunch of things that make up semantically identical (or very similar) XML, which will break regular expressions.

So the real answer is 'use an xpath' which is an XML expression that is ... rather like a directory path. As an illustrative example in perl (which will work on Windows).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented' )->parse( \*DATA );

foreach my $match ( $twig->root->get_xpath('//first/second/third') ) {
    print $match ->text, "\n";
}

$twig->print;

__DATA__
<root>
<first>
    <second>
        <third>match here</third>
    </second>
</first>
<second>
   <first>
      <third>not a match</third>
   </first>
</second>
<first> <second>
        <third>another match here</third></second>
</first>
<someparent>
   <another>
      <first><second><third>deeper nested match</third></second></first>
   </another>
</someparent>
</root>
```

An 'xpath' of `//first/second/third` will find the elements you want (`//` at the beginning denotes 'all descendants of current'). I think Notepad++ supports XML plugins.